Handling multiple custom domains login using single Auth. Provider
Our portal uses custom domains to cater to Spanish and French customers. We've integrated an Auth.provider to handle logins(external application is X). However, the provider defaults to the Spanish domain, preventing us from redirecting users to the French domain, even when specified in the startURL parameter.
Specific Issues:
Direct Redirection to French Domain: Attempts to directly redirect to the French domain using the startURL parameter result in errors.
Site URL Parameter: Using the siteURL parameter allows successful login but still redirects to the Spanish domain.
Question:
Is there a way to configure the authentication provider to handle multiple custom domains and redirect users to the appropriate domain based on their language or region?

Hi, thanks for your question. Are you using multiple/separate sites, or just custom domains? If you're using multiple sites then you could look at this article, or this related to difference experiences might help.

Thanks for your response Callum. One site and two custom domains pointing to the same site.

You either have two auth providers (typical) and then mess with how they're engaged by the various UX flows or build logic into your auth provider (if custom, untypical)
